# Install octave using homebrew

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew, octave

I found a blog on how to do this here https://www.nesono.com/node/356  but when I do

```
brew install octave
```

I get

```
Error: No available formula for octave
```

I am on Mountain Lion 10.8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your version of homebrew updated? Make sure to run `brew doctor` and `brew update`. I did a quick search using `brew search octave` and got this:

> homebrew/science/octave

So it exists in the formulas. You can find it [here on Github](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/blob/master/octave.rb).

Comment: This is heading right direction: I had to change ownership of /usr/local to allow homebrew to do git update. I still have issue with Xcode version because I am unable to update my apple id credentials and thus download from apple store.

Comment: @javadba Does installing octave work now?

Comment: I got farther with this, but it did not complete successfully.  I found a completely different way to do the octave installation (not using homebrew) and went with that.